# Open/Collapse Section based on the values selected when creating a case

Tags: visualforce

I have a section with a Visualforce page in Case detail page. The Visualforce page shows a long text or a short sentence depending on some values selected when creating a case.

Is it possible to show the long text with the section open and then to have the section collapsed when the short sentence is displayed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made a Javascript button that expands or collapses sections using the twistSection() function:

```
imgs = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 

for(var x in imgs) 

    if(imgs[x].className=='hideListButton' || imgs[x].className=='showListButton') 

       twistSection(imgs[x])
```

I don't know your exact criteria, but you could posibly build that into the if statement to show/hide that particular section.  There's also a twistAllSections() function that you can play around with.